# how to merge multiple varchar rows into one row in sql

Tags: merge

I have below source requirement 
source

```
No  note_num    note_lines  Notes
1234567 21  1   Called xyz @ the FA and confirmed that we paid   
1234567 21  2   income to the client on the 01.01.9999. This      
1234567 21  3   amounted to £250.00 nett. I have confirmed that
1234567 21  4   I will arrange for documents confirming this to be
1234567 21  5   sent out to her. Referred back to Kirk in order   
1234567 21  6   to amend income slices for the designation.
```

I need the target output as below

```
No  Notes
1234567 Called xyz @ the FA and confirmed that we paid income to the client on the 01.01.9999. This amounted to £250.00 nett. I have confirmed that I will arrange for documents confirming this to be sent out to her. Referred back to Kirk in order to amend income slices for the designation.
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to use `FOR XML PATH`, which has become somewhat of a standard replacement for `GROUP_CONCAT` in SQL Server;

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT no FROM mytable)
SELECT no, 
    STUFF(
    (
      SELECT CAST(' ' as varchar(max)) + notes
      FROM mytable
      WHERE mytable.no = cte.no
      ORDER BY note_lines
      FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '')
FROM
    cte
ORDER BY
    no ASC;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52a6f/1).